# Get Date object from String in form 2012-07-26 23:59:59

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have the input string as `2012-07-27` and I want the output as **`Date`** but with the same format like `2012-07-27`

#### Code

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

        try {
            Date today = df.parse("20-12-2005 23:59:59");
            System.out.println("Today = " + df.format(today));

                     } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

#### Output

```
20-12-2005 23:59:59
```

But it's string object I want the same output (`20-12-2005 23:59:59`) as date object not as string object.

How can I get the **`Date`** in the form `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)` returns a Date, `SimpleDateFormat.format(Date)` returns a String

Comment: Date today = df.parse("20-12-2005 23:59:59"); Dont this line give you string in Date as you are looking for.

Comment: By the way, if you are using `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");` , then your parsing should be like `Date today = df.parse("2005-12-20 23:59:59");` and Date today is already your **Date** object

Answer (score 2):

**`Date today`** is the `date` object you get for input `String`. There are nothing like formatted dates in Java. Date is always just date object. You perform all sorts of operations on that date object and when you want to Store (or) display just apply `format()`

```
df.format(today) // is just for formatting and display purpose.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is difference in your format passed to `SimpleDateFormat` and way you are passing date string. You should Also use `HH`

```
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date today = df.parse("20-12-2005 23:59:59");
        System.out.println("Today = " + df.format(today));
                       //To Print Real Today 
                    System.out.println("Real Today = " + df.format(new Date()));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class has many deprecated methods and the only correct way to create it right now is via a long (read doc for details).

You should look into [GregorialCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) where you can pass some constant fields of Calendar as attributes.

If you want to input the date from your String, I would either do a custom parser that creates a calendar or something like [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/StringToCalender.shtml).

Hope I helped :)